# How do I copy text in the middle of a section to the end of that same section using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I need to copy this text `<p><i>Updated on 10/01/19</i></p>` from the middle of the section to the end of the section using XSLT.

Here is the section containing the text:

```
<section property="ktp:explanation" typeof="ktp:Explanation" 
  class="ktp-explanation jasper-exclude">
  <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" 
    class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude" data-title="Explanation">
    <section property="ktp:subsection" typeof="ktp:feedback" 
      class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude" data-title="ReKap">
      <p class="reKap-title"><b>ReKap</b></p>
      <ul class="list-bullet">
        <li>Spindle afferents sense tension and stretching 
          of intrafusal muscle fibers.</li>
        <li>The tendon tap reflex
          stretches the intrafusal fibers, 
          initiating a contraction to restore initial muscle
          length (myotatic reflex).</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section property="ktp:subsection" typeof="ktp:feedback" 
      class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude" data-title="Analysis">
      <p class="analysis-title"><b>Analysis</b></p>
      <p><b>The correct answer is E. Spindle afferents</b> 
        and other sensory fibers innervate the <b>intrafusal fibers</b> 
        and detect changes in muscle stretch and tension.</p>
      <p>
        <i>Updated on 10/01/19</i></p>
    </section>
    <section property="ktp:subsection" typeof="ktp:feedback" 
      class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude atom-exclude" 
      data-title="High Yield Breakdown">
      <p>High Yield Breakdown placeholder text.</p>
    </section>
    <section property="ktp:subsection" typeof="ktp:feedback" 
      class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude atom-exclude" 
      data-title="Discussion">
      <p>Discussion text.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
<section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" 
  data-title="Resources" class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude">
  <p><i>MedEssentials (4th Ed.):</i> pp. 202</p>
  <p><i>First Aid (2019): </i> pp. 498.1</p>
  <iframe class="armando" height="500" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bY0oQnflmog?start=466"></iframe>
</section>
</section>
```

Here is section of my script that runs the transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Explanation']"> 
  <section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" 
    class="ktp-explanation-section jasper-exclude" data-title="Explanation">  
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'ReKap']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Analysis']"/>
    <xsl:copy-of
      select="following-sibling::xhtml:section
        [@data-title = 'Resources']/xhtml:iframe"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'High Yield Breakdown']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Discussion']"/>
  </section>
</xsl:template>
```

I need the line `<p><i>Updated on 10/01/19</i></p>` to be placed after the `iframe` section. How would I do that?

Comment: I miss two elements for understanding correctly your question: a) the desired ouput, and b) the description of what you want to copy: is that any paragraph containing the word "updated", or what?

Comment: The desired output is the same, just lower down in the section compared to where it is currently. It would be any paragraph containing "Updated on". I basically need it removed from its current location and re-placed in its new location after the section containing "iframe".

Comment: I had to reindent your XSLT code and XML input on order to make the logic appear. I will not inject my code into your code because a lot of solutions are possible, depending on the context which I ignore. Basically, you have to do two things: a) suppress form the output, any paragraph containing the string "Updated on" and b) adding the information you suppressed elsewhere into the output. I will explain it below.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment above, basically, you have to do two things: a) suppress form the output, any paragraph containing the string "Updated on" and b) adding the information you suppressed elsewhere into the output.

a) For suppressing the paragraphs containing the string "Updated on", try to add a template as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:if test="not (descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(), "Updated on")])">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

b) for inserting somewhere inside the `section[@data-title='Explanation']`, try:

```
<xsl:copy-of 
  select="xhtml:section/p[descendant-or-self::*[contains(text(), "Updated on")]]">
```

Since you don't provide a so called minimal working example, I am not able to test it, but you can try it.